# "no viable alternative postgresql" error message

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
  select c_bpartner.name , c_bpartner.c_bpartner_id
  from c_bpartner
  where name in (select ad_org.name
  from ad_org
  where name='orgnamehere'
   )
 where isvendor='Y'
```

Im getting error `no viable alternative at input "select"`. The error is on the `select` in the sub query.

Comment: Is type of `c_bpartner.name` compatible with type of `ad_org.name`?

Comment: yes they are both varchar(60) if that is what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last `where isvendor='Y'` and remplace it with `AND isvendor='Y'`

```
      select c_b.name , c_b.c_bpartner_id
      from c_bpartner c_b
      where c_b.isvendor='Y' AND
             c_b.name in (select a_o.name
                      from ad_org a_o
                      where a_o.name='orgnamehere'
                      )
```

Comment: May be a confusion with table name. I updated my answer. Try it